# Gradle: cannot create ExtensiblePolymorphicDomainObjectContainer

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Suppose I have an extension interface like this:

```kotlin
interface MyExtension {
    abstract val container: ExtensiblePolymorphicDomainObjectContainer<MyBaseClass>
}
```

When I try to create an instance of this extension via this:

```kotlin
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        val extension = project.extensions.create<MyExtension>("myExtension")
    }
}
```

It seems that Gradle (at least as of version 7.6.1) will have trouble applying a `MyPlugin` due to being unable to create the extension, in turn due to being able to implement the `container` property properly.

Is it a limitation of Gradle or the Kotlin DSL requiring a workaround (eg. making `MyExtension` an abstract class and injecting an `ObjectFactory` specifically), or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gradle can only create specific types of properties on managed types](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_gradle_types.html#mutable_managed_properties)

These are

- `Property<T>`
- `RegularFileProperty`
- `DirectoryProperty`
- `ListProperty<T>`
- `SetProperty<T>`
- `MapProperty<K, V>`
- `ConfigurableFileCollection`
- `ConfigurableFileTree`
- `DomainObjectSet<T>`
- `NamedDomainObjectContainer<T>`

In [Gradle v8.2](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/24657), `ExtensiblePolymorphicDomainObjectContainer<T>` will be supported. Until then they must be created manually using `ObjectFactory`.

One way of doing this is by injecting the ObjectFactory into the constructor:

```kotlin
import javax.inject.Inject
import org.gradle.api.*
imports org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*

abstract class MyExtension @Inject constructor(
  private val objects: ObjectFactory,
) {
  val container: ExtensiblePolymorphicDomainObjectContainer<MyBaseClass> =
    objects.polymorphicDomainObjectContainer()
}
```

##### Pro tip: Kotlin DSL accessors for `NamedDomainObjectContainer`s

Note that even though Gradle will automatically create `NamedDomainObjectContainer` properties it's usually a good idea to create one manually and add it as an extension.

```kotlin
abstract class MyExtension @Inject constructor(
  private val objects: ObjectFactory,
) : ExtensionAware {
// *all* types that Gradle instantiates are automatically ExtensionAware,
// but adding the interface explicitly helps with IDE hints
  
  val namedContainer: NamedDomainObjectContainer<MyBaseClass> =
    objects.domainObjectContainer(MyBaseClass::class).also {
      extensions.add("namedContainer", it)
    }
}
```

This is verbose and weird - so why bother?

By adding `namedContainer` as an extension, Gradle will automatically generate some nice [type-safe Kotlin DSL accessors](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors) for any element that is added.

So, if in your plugin you add an element.

```kotlin
abstract class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
  override fun apply(project: Project) {
    val extension = project.extensions.create<MyExtension>("myExtension")
    extension.namedContainer.register("anElement") { ... }
  }
}
```

In any build script, there will be an easy way to access the element in a type-safe and IDE friendly way

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
plugins {
  id("my.plugin")
}

myExtension {
  namedContainer.anElement { // auto generated accessor
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if other types (eg. `NamedDomainObjectSet`) will be added in the same manner?

Comment: @KelvinChung I don't know, but you can always [make a request](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues). However, [`NamedDomainObjectContainer` extends `NamedDomainObjectSet`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectContainer.html), so there's very little difference in practice.